# How to get one record from sqlite and display in tableview

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

What I want to do is take the input from a text field (i.e cust_name), match and fetch the record from database with column cust_name.
Database has table `cust` and column `cust_name`, `address`. I want to find a way to display the data in tablview of `QSqlTableModel`.

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel;
model->setTable("cust");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(0,1);
ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(5,1);

ui->list->setModel(model);
ui->list->setModelColumn(1);

model->select();
```

This successfully displays the whole table named cust. I want to be able to change it into displaying the single record matching the search term.

Comment: Add a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and filter there or change current model to use a `QSqlQueryModel` with a custom SELECT statement

Comment: I achieved it by using QSortFilterSqlQueryModel subclass of QSqlQueryModel.

Answer (score 1):

Use function `index()` to access custom row/column.

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel;
int value = model->index(row,column).data().toInt();
```

In your situation like this:

```
int value = model->index((model->rowCount()-1),column).data().toInt();
```

or custom sql query :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```